# Have to be doing, am/is/are/was/were to be doing

Tags: progressive-aspect

Can I say ' I am to be doing'?
 Similarly, I have to be doing'
Is it possible in any sense?
Can you refer me any book in which you saw this use?

Comment: Yes, both are possible, but they are overly convoluted grammar.  "I will do ..." or "I have to do ..." normally work just fine.  Is there a reason you must use these, or are you just curious?

Comment: Suddenly these things came in my mind and I asked. I'm very curious to know how they can exacly be used. Please give me some examples.

Comment: I'm having to do.

Comment: Variations between  I am having to do and I have to be doing. My own sentence is ' I am to be preparing my lessons all by myself.' Is it correct?

Comment: I am to be doing is very unusual.  I am having to do = I find myself in the position of doing something. The assistant teacher is sick so I am having to do all the lesson preparation.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is variations on the [future progressive (or continuous) tense.](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futurecontinuous.html).  This is used to describe ongoing action that will happen in the future.  As such, it's not common since the simple future tense is sufficient, but is is used:

If you are going to use it, however, you should establish some kind of parallel time frame to show that your action is *continuing* at the same time.

> Tomorrow I will be preparing my lessons by myself **since my wife will be out visiting her family**.
>
> Next week I am to be spending time with my entire family while they are in town for the holiday.
>
> Next year I have to be traveling a lot more for business while [something else is going on]

It's difficult to come up with good examples for these since it's easier to write them using the simple future tense:

> Tomorrow I am going to prepare my lessons by myself since my wife will be out visiting her family

So while it is *possible* to use these verb tenses, I don't recommend it.

[Edit] "Have to be doing" could be either present or future tense, depending on how it's used.  It suggests a *requirement* to do something, either now or at some point in the future.

> Although I would rather be out playing, Mother says I have to be doing my homework.

Although again "I have to do ..." is generally simpler and more clear.

> Although I would rather go out and play, Mother says I have to do my homework.

Comment: Now I have to be writing your own sentences.

Comment: Is it correct to say 'Now you have to be writing...'

Comment: Yes, it's correct, it's the [present progressive tense](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html) to talk about *ongoing* action.  However, good English *style* is to use the simple present unless you really must use the progressive.  "Now you have to write" or "Now I have to write ..."

Comment: It's so kind of you to answer me soon.

Comment: I have to be doing is future??

Comment: @Lambie yeah I guess "have to be doing" could be either present or future.  Let me edit.

Comment: One might, though, say: Now, /I have to be doing my work/ to signal to someone that they should piss off and leave you alone.